# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL when upgrading to Angular-CLI + Angular 4

Tags: angular

I updated my project and everything was fine in Angular 2 and now 4. I now brought in `Angular-CLI 1.0.0` and it will not find the json file for primeNG.

```
 constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getFiles() {
        return this.http.get('mock_data/data.json')
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => <TreeNode[]> res.json().data)
            .then(data => { return data; });
    }
```

Is throwing the error and I tried adding a `./` copied the path of the folder to double check.

In my `index.html` file I have `<base href="/">` and the directory is under `src`

Error:

```
core.es5.js:1084 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:4200/mock_data/data.json
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? Like a screenshot

Comment: @echonax done..

Comment: @Drew1208 can u try `base href = "."`

Comment: Try moving `mock_data` into the `assets` folder and then update the url with `'assets/mock_data/data.json'`.

Comment: @echonax that was it!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Drew1208 I provided it as an answer :-) since the cli is building it differently than we see it, it is better to use the assets folder for external data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `mock_data` into the `assets` folder and then update the url with `'assets/mock_data/data.json'`.

---

Suggested edit:

Another way : **only** add `"mock-data"` into `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
"assets": [
            "assets",
            "favicon.ico",
            "mock-data"
        ]
```